# Why console shows different things when I use querySelector()?

Tags: javascript, html, element, console.log, queryselector

when I use **document.querySelector()**, At first, I can see html tag in console like this.

```
// this is JS code
allProducts.forEach((product) => {
**const productList = document.querySelector('.product-list');**
console.log(productList);
});
```

```
// console.log
<div class="product-list">
      <!-- <div class="product">
        <img src="imgs/imgs/blue_s.png">
        <p>female, small size</p>
      </div> -->
    </div>
```

but after page refresh, console shows this.

```
//console.log
div.product-list (This is object.)
 accessKey:""
 align: ""
 ariaAtomic: null
 ariaAutoComplete: null
 ariaBrailleLabel: null
 ariaBrailleRoleDescription: null
 ...
```

I read MDN .querySelector() page(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
It says .quesySelector()'s return value type is 'Element'. But still, **I don't know which one is 'Element' type** and **why I had to see html tags like first one before page refresh.**

+) I am using Chrome browser.

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the content of the console as text to the post, I've no clue what is actually logged. And specify also the browser you're working with.

Comment: @Teemu I modified original post. (second console shows 'div.product-list' object. I could see properties.)Sorry that I couldn't post console screen shot because of low level of stackoverflow reputation

Comment: Use `console.dir` to always see the properties.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks! It worked! But I still wonder Why I could see object properties even when I use console.log() and then page refresh. Could you give me hint?

Comment: I don't know, by my experience, Chromium DevTools console always logs a textual representation of an element (i.e. markup), and dirs the actual structure, I haven't noticed any difference after refreshing (but not saying there wouldn't be a difference, I've preferred Firefox for testing).